# Will there be any side effects of running a Jenkins job every 5mins

Tags: jenkins

Will there be any side effects of running a Jenkins job every 5 mins or say 2 mins for days (too frequent runs) I mean overhead or side effects in terms of memory over long period.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean running as in the job actually executing or running as in Jenkins checking source control for changes?

Comment: yes like polling scm or any service

Comment: I won't put this as an answer at its just my experience - but I've seen Jenkins run on a t1.micro EC2 instance with its jobs set to poll SCM every minute with perfectly acceptable performance...

Comment: thanks Jon, even experience feedback helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The only disadvantage I know of for having polling frequency kept high is when it is less than a minute. Sometimes there are two commits submitted in the same minute. Jenkins won't build them both. It will build only the latest commit but that won't matter if you just want the latest version to be built.